# Async / Await Resolving Not Waiting

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have the following test case where I am getting a value, adding a filter, getting the value again and comparing them. If they are not equal then the test passes. This was working with Control Flow, but I have been asked to update to async/await as the control flow has been deprecated in protractor.

The problem that I am running into is that the `membersAfter` is resolving at the beginning of the test and not waiting until after the filter is applied.

```
listOfSimpleFilters.forEach((filter, index) => {
    it(`Test Each Filter Type With Cohorts ${index}`, async () => {
        const membersBefore = await cohortView.cohortMemberCount.getText()
        await cohortView.openFilters()
        await filterList.addSimpleFilters(filter)
        const membersAfter = await cohortView.cohortMemberCount.getText()
        await expect(membersBefore !== membersAfter).toBe(true, `The Members Before Filter: ${membersBefore} and the Members after Filter: ${membersAfter} are not different`)
    })
})
```

Just wondering how to get it to actually wait until after I apply the filter to get the `membersAfter` amount.

I did attempt to do a `Promise.all()` but that did not work either.

Comment: Are all those functions you apply `await` for actually `async`?

Comment: The `cohortView.openFilters()` and `filterList.addSimpleFilters()` are both using async/await if that is what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `.forEach()` loops. 
Once I switched them over to something like this:

```
for (const filter of listOfSimpleFilters) {
    it(`Test Each Filter Type With Cohorts`, async () => {
        const membersBefore = await cohortView.cohortMemberCount.getText()
        await cohortView.openFilters()
        await filterList.addSimpleFilters(filter)
        const membersAfter = await cohortView.cohortMemberCount.getText()
        await expect(membersBefore !== membersAfter).toBe(true, `The Members Before Filter: ${membersBefore} and the Members after Filter: ${membersAfter} are not different`)
    })
}
```

The problems I was having went away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code inside the "it" block.

Everything inisde the "it" block is executed first

Comment: They are inside the `it` block